Is axial symmetry the same as transverse isometry?
I was reading this paper
ArXiv link
And trying to picture everytime he mentioned "transverse isotropic plate" I began to imagine something that is equal on all directions on a plane, but not necessarily in the other direction.
Isn't this the definition of axially symmetric? Or is isometry necessary?
